# How to distinguish between a string and number in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

How can I distinguish between a string and number when logging to the console with Chrome Dev Tools?

[image: Image from another post]

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18144737/38765) to "Blue number in Chrome Dev Console?" has a screenshot of what happens when you pass a string to `console.log` and what happens when you pass a number.

I can make out a difference in colour when it's blown up this large, but have difficulty when it is its usual size.

By contrast, in Ruby, distinguishing between an Integer object and a String object is easy - doing `puts foo.inspect` will give you quotation marks around a string, but not around the integer.

Comment: quick fix: use the console Dark Theme

Comment: also - look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777454/google-chrome-customize-developer-tools-theme-color-schema

Comment: FWIW `console.log('%o', 'a')`

Comment: Evaluating `"a"` in the console spits back `"a"` (with quotes) -- it seems `console.log` removes the quotes in some circumstances